# DDD: How to save the order of aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have the two Aggregates 'notebook' and 'note'.

When I use the role 'aggregates reference only by there ids', I think I have two options:

```
Notebook(List<NoteId>, [other properties])
Note([other properties])
```

or

```
Notebook([other properties])
Note(NotebookId, [other properties])
```

With the first option, I need two DB calls to show all notes of a notebook (one to get the list and the second to load the notes).

So my current favorite is the second option. Now I have few options in my mind to save the order of the notes, where anyone has some disadvantages.

What is a good approach to solve my problem? Or is the first option better and the two DB calls are negligible?

Can anybody help?

Big THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the order of the Notes is important, at least related to the Notebook, so maybe it should be part of the domain. If yes, I would suggest to store it together with the Note. Or use some other information of the Note to give an ordering when a list is loaded.

If not, why is the order relevant? I mean, the two entities have a related but  separated lifecycle, or at least it looks: one aggregate - the Notebook - has a list that only references the other - the Note. Hence no direct interaction is planned. But, given the the domain is correctly modelled (there's not enough information to say something about it), somewhere you need a ordered list of Notes. The only way to have it as you need it is to store the information (or use one already stored), otherwise the hypothesis (order is relevant) is not valid anymore.

---

*update after infos about number of Notes and their size*

It looks that your domain is organized in this way:

- a root entity, the Notebook, where the order of each Note, with only its ID, is also stored: any change in the order will be updated from here, not from the Note
- another root entity, the Note, with its own lifecycle and its own 'actions' (operations that trigger a change in the entity)

Whenever you load the Notebook, you must load also the Note and it's order to show it correctly ordered. On the other side, when you change the order, this structure allows you to have a single action (or operation) on the Notebook, for example *changeOrder(NoteId)*, that updates the order of the given Note and, if needed, changes the order of all the others. The trick, here, is that when you persist the Notebook you work just with the ID of the Note, so you don't have to load all the entity, but just a part of it, update and save it again. So, how big is the Note entity is not important, because you don't use it all. Hence, at every change you could trigger an update of all the couples (NoteID, order) for that Notebook. You can't do differently. But, to support this you need a single function in the repository where you load the ID of the Note and its order and you save it again; that should be not so expensive.

On the other side, all the actions that operate directly on the Note should load it, hence you have to load all. But in this case is required to load all, and save all, because you are changing the Note itself.

Anyway, the way you persist the order is totally demanded to the persistence layer, that is built over the domain. I mean, the domain has a Notebook and a set of Notes with order 1, 2, 3, etc.

Even if I don't think that this needs such a complex solution, you could use a totally differen way to store the order: you can use for example steps of 100 (so 100, 200, 300, etc): each new Note is put in the middle of the old two ones, and is the only one to be saved each time. Every since a while you run a job, or something else, that just normalizes all the values restoring the 100 steps (or whatever you use to persit the order). As I said, this looks an overcomplicated solution to the problem, but it also shows the fact that the entities of the domain could be totally different from the Persitence ones.

Comment: Well, if I store the position together with the note, how to update the order?
If I have 1000 notes and I want to push the last one to the first position, I need to update all other 999 notes and there positions?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Whatever is the structure of your domain is (Notebook root entity and Notes never directly managed or, Notebook and Notes as stand alone root entities), if the order is important for the domain, whenever you change it you must save it. So, if you add a Note which should stay before all the other, at the end you are changing also the order of 999 other Notes, hence you must update them to store it correctly.  Tricks to save DB requests/updates is a problem that could (and should) be solved in the persistence layer, where you translate your entities from Domain to Database.

Comment: Notebook and Note are two separate aggregates with its one entities and value objects. Notes are "too big" to load there everytime when I load the notebook aggregate.

Comment: Okay, I think that is a good compromise, thanks. ^^
But why I need a repository function to update the order? I could load the notbook aggregate with the list of (Position, NodeID), update the list and save the notebook. So the notebook would be updated completely.

When I add a new note, I would store it and create a domain event. Something could react to that event and create a command to update the notebook's list. Is that a good solution?

Comment: You don't need it. If you save the Notebook with the Notes it's ok, as long as you use just the Id and the order. For the new Note, I would do something different: I ask the Notebook for a new Note, then I would show something to manage/change it. Together with this also a function to remove it. If it's empty it's not a problem, but it's up to how your domain is designed. Anyway, I would stay away from event handlers for domain changes, because you have to manage all the side cases If something goes wrong.